# Python subscript syntax clarification

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, syntax

Can you clarify what the `[:, :5]` part of the code does in the following code segment?

```
for i in range(5):
        weights = None
        test_inputs = testset[i][:, :5]
        test_inputs = test_inputs.astype(np.float32)
        test_answer = testset[i][:, :5]
        test_answer = code_answer(test_answer)
```

Comment: That's not normal Python syntax, it's Numpy syntax.

Answer (score 0):

this is explained in the [numpy indexing guide](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html) of the manual. this is not standard python syntax.

if you have an array `a`, `a[:]` returns a view (not a copy; assigning to this will change `a`) on the whole array; `a[:5]` a view on elements `0, 1, ..., 4`.

`numpy` allows more-dimensional arrays to be indexed with `a[i, j]` instead of the pure python version `a[i][j]`.

this should cover all your cases.

Answer (score 0):

This code probably uses `numpy` arrays.

Numpy defines more elaborate array slicing, similar to Matlab style.

The `[:, :5]` means that from you array (probably a 2D array, returned from `tester[i]`) you take all the rows (designated by `:`) and then it takes columns from the beginning until but not including column 5.

Each part of the slicing expression follows regular Python slicing syntax.

The `[:, :5]` itself is actually interpreted like this `[(:, :5)]`, since in Python a comma separated values without parenthesis are interpreted as a tuple.

The array object can handle tuples that denote complex slicing patterns.

This is in short the meaning of this syntax.

For more information, you may want to visit the numpy page, you can start at www.scipy.org.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, the array being referenced is from the
numpy package (see it's home [page](http://www.numpy.org/))

An example should help.  First create a multi-dimensional array structure similar to what the code provided is manipulating:

```
from numpy import *
a=arange(36).reshape(6,6)
b=a.reshape(6,3,2).swapaxes(0,2)
print b

[[[0  6 12 18 24 30]
  [2  8 14 20 26 32]
  [4 10 16 22 28 34]]
 [[1  7 13 19 25 31]
  [3  9 15 21 27 33]
  [5 11 17 23 29 35]]]
```

The [:,:5] syntax is an array slicing mechanism that culls all 
component array entries beyond the fifth:

```
print b[1][:,:5]

[[1  7 13 19 25]
 [3  9 15 21 27]
 [5 11 17 23 29]]
```

Comment: You are not answering the question. Just showing the output does not explain what the output *means* or what the operator does.